# How to profile OpenTK C# application with CodeXL?

Tags: c#, .net, profiling, opentk

I wanted to switch from gDEBugger to CodeXL as CodeXL is the successor of gdeb and even has Visual Studio integration.

However, there are some problems with the integration for me. I'm using VS2013, the most recent CodeXL version and compile against .NET 4.5.

- It starts the executable from the obj folder, not the bin folder. Thus, if I start CodeXL debugging, it doesn't find my engines DLL or any other stuff copied with the output, as these reside in the bin folder. I fixed this by manually copying the files there, but that's a rather dirty solution if you ask me.
- I don't know how to log CodeXL redundant state changes with CodeXL, the thing I used gDEBugger mostly for. I can only start my project in the CodeXL "Debug Mode", but this one doesn't log redundant state changes. If I switch to the required "Analyze Mode", I don't get any statistics at all and can't even start the application, buttons and the statistics view are disabled.

Is someone successful using CodeXL with OpenTK and can tell me how to proceed? It boils down to the following two questions:

- How to change the executable path to correct the obj <-> bin folder problem?
- How to log redundant state changes of the OpenGL application?

Comment: I've  not used CodeXL, but to fix the path issue you could just point your Target (bin) and Intermediate (obj) output paths to point to the same place in the project properties.

Comment: I thought about that, but then I mix two folders in one and don't have a clean bin-output anymore.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a perfect solution but would ensure you have the latest files every time you build inside your "obj" folder, you could go into your project properties and under "Build Events" set your "Post-build event command Line:" to:

```
copy "$(SolutionDir)\YourProjectName\bin\Debug" "$(ProjectDir)\obj\Debug"
```

Assuming of course your active build is set to "Debug" and also replace your "YourProjectName" with your project name :-)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing now, there are some more placeholders to automate the output paths. It's a really dirty solution. Also still don't know how to really profile redundant calls. I give you the bounty anyways so it's not lost and you can need it ;D